# How to stop wordpress from showing the selected category on top of others in the category selection?

Tags: categories, wp-admin

By default in the category chooser at the edit post screen wordpress displays the selected categories on top of the others, i find that extremely annoying and i would like to disable the feature even if i need a hack for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I got this right, you need this plugin: [Category Checklist Tree](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-checklist-tree/).

> On the post editing screen, after saving a post, you will notice that
>   the checked categories are displayed on top, breaking the category
>   hierarchy. This plugin removes that "feature".
>
> Additionally, it automatically scrolls to the first checked category.
>
> Works with custom taxonomies too.